# Как получить изменённый state в React js

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hook

Вопрос довольно примитивный, но конкретного ответа на него я не нашел. В общем у меня есть некий стейт, который должен корректно отображаться при нажатии на кнопки например

```
 const [index, setIndex] = useState<number>(0)
```

Если я хочу отрендерить этот индекс на сайте например следующий образом

```
<p>{index}</p>
```

то все работает корректно. При инкременте индекс добавляется, при декременте уменьшается. Делаю с помощью двух простейших функций

```
function increment () {
    setIndex(index + 1)
}
function decrement () {
    setIndex(index - 1)
}
```

но стоит мне добавить например в эти функции console.log(index) мне он начинает давать устаревший стейт. И при работе с этим индексом, он мне всё так же выдает устаревшее состояние. Но если я буду вызывать консоль лог в теле компонента, то он будет показывать уже измененный стейт. Я много прочитал по поводу того, что useState это асинхронный хук. Но я по прежнему не понимаю почему так происходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После смены состояния происходит **ререндеринг** с обновленными значениями. По-этому то, что в самом теле компонента, вызовется заново и покажет измененный стейт.

В вашем же примере Вы вызываете изменения стейта, но, не дожидаясь ререндера, сразу же берете текущее значение и пишите его в консоль. На тот момент оно еще не обновлено.

Правильное отображение нового значения

```
function increment () {
    const newIndex = index + 1;
    setIndex(newIndex);
    console.log(newIndex);
}
```

Или можно "подписаться" на изменения стейта через useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('index updated', index);
}, [index]);
```

Comment: Да, по большей части ваш метод мне и нужен был. Спасибо !